# Is there a language in which the verb "to ask" can be followed by a dative case?

Tags: syntax, verbs, list-of-languages, cases

So far as I know, the ditransitive verb "to ask" takes two accusatives in German (fragen), and the verb "to give" takes one dative and one accusative in many languages.
Is there a language in which the verb "to ask" can be followed by a dative case (assuming that the language has a distinct dative case)?

Comment: When does *fragen* take 2 accusatives in German?  It seems one can say either *fragen* + acc or *eine Frage stellen* + dat.  In most languages that I know, the equivalent of *eine Frage fragen* sounds oddly redundant.  Only in English can it work, because they have different roots.

Comment: This website [link](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/German_Language/German_I#Dative_Verbs_and_Double_Accusative_Verbs) gives four verbs taking double accusatives, including the verb "fragen".

Comment: [German wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fragen)  gives an example :Er fragt sie, ob sie möchte.

Comment: The use of *fragen* with double accusative is really marginal. A sentence like *\*Sie fragt ihn ein Wasser* is ungrammatical. The only cases I can think of are *Sie fragt ihn etwas* (She asks him about something) and the question *Was fragt sie ihn?* (What is is asking him?)

Comment: @jknappen It doesn't need to be an NP to be an argument of the verb: In the example discenter gave, the subordinate clause can be regarded as the second object, and since you would ask for that sentence with *was* in accusative, couldn't you say that the clause is an accusative object?

Comment: @lemontree: I won't consider subordinate clauses to be an accusative (or dative or whatever) object, they are just that: Subordinate clauses. But my feeling of grammar is heavily biased by taking several years of Latin :-)

Comment: @jnkappen I'm not completely sure about it either - my intuition tells me that there should be some kind of accusative object in that position which is taken by the clause, but I don't know whether, syntactically, CPs can actually be assigned cases, can't recall having seen something like that before. BTW, I learnt some Latin too and this just for fun, I wasn't even forced to or something, just liked the grammar, but you're not the first one I hear from that Latin can do weird things to your head ;)

Comment: English: in "He asked her a question", "her" is dative, even though we don't say "He asked a question to her".  We would use 'of' (trying to hint that the reply comes 'from'), but logically the question goes 'to' the recipient.

Comment: @aml: There is a distinction between thematic roles and case. 'Her' is not morphologically marked as dative, so there seems to be little reason for us to treat it as taking the dative case.

Comment: In Russian it can be followed by Dative case but the meaning will be different (the person in Dative would specify not whom you are asking but for whom).

Comment: Why don't  you specify "in declined languages"?

Answer (score 2):

In Russian, [по]просить, 'to ask', can be followed by the Dative case object, then the meaning is 'to ask for somebody', like it is often used in prayers to saints when you ask a saint that she ask God to give you something, e.g. "Попроси мне и моим близким здоровья", 'Ask for health for me and my family'. Here "мне" 'for me' and "моим близким" 'for my family' are both in Dative, and "здоровья" 'for health' is in Genitive.

Comment: I think, this is an incorrect example of verb governance. The verb "to ask" governs the noun case for an object who is being asked, not the reason of a request. In other words, "to ask *him*" (accusative) is correct while "to ask *by voice*" (instrumental) is incorrect. Also, in English, "to ask" has two meanings (to beg and to question), and the OP definitely means "fragen" (not "bitten"), while your answer is about the meaning, "to beg".

Comment: I agree with @bytebuster that this is not what the question is asking for, add, however, that you have the same construction with Latin posco. For example, Plautus writes: sine dote posco tuam sororem filio “I ask for your sister (acc.) for my son (dat.) without a dowry”.

Answer (score 2):

Turkish:
Ona nedenini sor.
Literal translation to German would be:
Frage ihm/ihr den Grund.
The asked person is in dative. The topic to be asked is in accusative.

Answer (score 1):

In French, the recipient of *demander* ('ask') is dative:

```
(1) Je  lui   demande de répondre à  cette question.
    1sg 3.DAT ask     of respond  to this  question
    I ask him to respond to this question.
```

In Late Archaic Chinese, 問 *wen* ('ask') can subcategorise for a recipient, which is also dative.

```
(2) 孔子    與   之    坐  而   問  焉
    Kongzi  yu  zhi   zuo er   wen yan
    Kongzi  COM 3.ACC sit CONJ ask 3.DAT
    Confucius sat with him and asked him.
```

In both cases, the verb can also take an accusative object meaning what is being asked. In addition, the dative case only appears when the recipient is a pronoun; otherwise a prepositional phrase appears, respectively *à* in French and *yu* in Late Archaic Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the previous answer in Czech, the verb "zeptat se" is actually being used when you're referring to the object of asking with dativ (but can not be used in the described meaning)